# Multiple threads to run parallel at fixed interval using ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

Objective: Monitor 5 json URLs every 5 seconds with 5 threads running parallel.

I want to run Multiple parallel threads to monitor JSON URLs at an interval of n-seconds each. I am using `ScheduledExecutorService` for this.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

for(NetworkBwXmlObject x : xmlDsList) {
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new processJsonUrl(x.getJsonUrl(),x.getId(), ctx), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

class processJsonUrl implements Runnable {

}
```

Is this the right way to create 5 threads to monitor 5 URLS. I don't want to use a thread pool here. All 5 threads have to be active till the lifecycle of the application.

Can `ScheduledExecutorService` help in my scenario or there is an alternate way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

ScheduledExecutorService  is a thread pool and it will do what you want.

Comment: The problem i am facing with this is that the executor starts 5 scheduled threads (scheduled to run at 5 sec rate) but all 5 threads run only once and not continuously at 5 sec intervals. Am i missing something here?

Comment: scheduleAtFixedRate does this. If your task is not repeating, then it has thrown an exception/error.  You need to catch this exception in the run() method otherwise it will store it in the Future object returned by this method, which you discard, and so you don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement that with Quartz, it's an easy way of achieving good solutions involving scheduled tasks:
http://quartz-scheduler.org/